# How to run using terminal on IntelliJ Idea using Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ IDEA and I would like to run my test through the terminal lines.

I already run my test using the Run button and my test are all passed. Now, my requirement in project is to run using the command lines/terminal. I really don't have any idea how to do it.

I'm using Appium as my tool for mobile automation.

This is all where my tests are located, C:\Users\ereyne\IdeaProjects\ioappium\src\test\java\io

[Tests location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h95V0.png)

I already look on google but all are in high level, can anyone provide me step by step process on how to do it?
[Test java classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkNaa.png)

This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>io.appium</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is my code in IntelliJ:

```
//package io;//package appium;

import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class appium {

public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
public WebDriverWait wait;
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
int CustomerNumber = 10088214;
int AccessCode = 44445555;
String SignIn = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button[3]";
String MakeaPayment = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button[4]";

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel XL API 28");
    dc.setCapability("udid", "ce041714789604830d"); //DeviceId from "adb devices" command //Tab S3-674ce8f9 S8-ce041714789604830d
    dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    dc.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");
    dc.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.loans.smartmoney");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.loans.smartmoney.MainActivity");
    dc.setCapability("noReset","true");
    dc.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),dc);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
}

@Test
public void testLoginTest() {

    //Login
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
            (By.xpath(SignIn)));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(SignIn)).click();

    driver.findElement(By.className("android.view.View")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(CustomerNumber));
    driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(1).click();
    driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(1).sendKeys(String.valueOf(AccessCode));
    driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button")).get(1).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
            (By.xpath(MakeaPayment)));
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

I run this is terminal: C:\Users\ereyne\IdeaProjects\ioappium>mvn appium.java

Errors: [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "appium.java". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generat e-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integr ation-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

I also try to run this in my terminal: C:\Users\ereyne\IdeaProjects\ioappium\src\test\java\io>javac appium.java

And the result is everything does not exist, just a sample error below.

appium.java:2: error: package io.appium.java_client does not exist import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;

Comment: Open a shell/terminal tool window in idea and run mvn test. You might need the bash plugin installed.

Comment: Hi @bmargulies, Yup already see that terminal, but I don't know what to write on those. I'm not really a coder type since I'm a manual tester.

Comment: If it is a maven project, go to the terminal(`Alt+F12` in intellij) and invoke `mvn test`. This is with the assumption that you have added your test files.

Comment: @Sachin - what do you mean that added my test files? I tried the 'mvn test' and it says it is not a recognized as an internal or external command. I also tried 'java <classname> and it didn't work.

Comment: C:\Users\ereyne\IdeaProjects\ioappium\src\test\java\io>java appium
Error: Could not find or load main class appium

C:\Users\ereyne\IdeaProjects\ioappium\src\test\java\io>mvn test
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: is mvn added to your environment classpath ?  open your terminal and type `mvn -v` to see if it display the maven version else you need to setup maven. You can refer to https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html to setup maven

Comment: @Sachin - yup I already have the maven in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ-IDEA actually has a built-in terminal that you can run maven commands in at a project level. Simply click the "terminal" button on the very bottom bar. If you don't see it, try "Alt+F12". If your terminal is disabled, press Shift twice, type "Terminal" and turn it on.

From there, you can run maven commands. The valid lifecycle phases are:

- clean
- validate
- compile
- test
- package
- verify
- install
- site
- deploy

So within that terminal, you'll already be on the right directory, and can run valid maven commands. For example

- mvn clean
- mvn verify
- mvn test -e

You will want the Maven-Compiler-Plugin, and either the Maven-Surefire-Plugin or Maven-Failsafe-plugin. For my own personal project, this is the pom.xml that I use containing those plugins.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The 'source' and 'target' denote what Java version my project uses. These plugins allow me to both run my project as a maven project, and have specific things happen at different instances of the lifecycle.

In my case, during the "verify" phase, maven triggers a plugin of mine to log results, and create a report.

If you're getting the error

> 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This means that Maven was not added to your PATH correctly. It can be a little confusing, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTRmukUvB50) helped me a lot.

If you want to check your maven installation, open a new terminal, and run the following

```
mvn -v
```

You should get the response (with your system details)

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Edit: To answer your question below in more detail, I use a TestRunner class designed for the Cucumber framework, and I do not have a main method in my program at all. My Test class is as follows:

```java
package Runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;


@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-pretty", "json:target/Cucumber.json"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features"},
        glue = {"StepDefinitions"},
        tags = {"@smoke"},
        monochrome = true
)
public class AppiumTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


}
```

As you can see, my Test class doesn't have any code inside of it, and simply points to specific tests that I've built, and executes those. In the case of using TestNG as a test suite, it will look a lot different, and is a little bit easier to understand what is being tested, but check these resources to make sure you understand what to do.

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml
https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/how-to-execute-testng-tests-with-maven-build/

Based on your reply, odds are, you've already got a TestNG suite built, and just need to tie it into maven.

The structure of a pom.xml is fairly straightforward, so you can use this to help you put the plugins you need into yours. I've included a copy of my pom.xml for a testing suite using Cucumber and Appium, just so you can see the format. I highly encourage you to keep the comments including the repository information in the event you need to update them in a hurry.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>MobileAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Test</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <param>Cucumber.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failIfNoSpecifiedTests>false</failIfNoSpecifiedTests>
                    <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see, in my pom.xml I have a plugin that generates a test report during the "Verify" phase of Maven. When I want to run a test, I will run

```
mvn clean verify
```

This clears out any of my old test results, and runs the maven "Verify" cycle. Verify will run the tests I specify, and then depending on the results of my tests, the maven build will either succeed or fail.

If you see a maven build failure, that doesn't mean your code failed to execute, it means that maven had a reason to fail a build. Read about the specific maven plugins and lifecycle phases to understand what causes build failures, and what behaviors to expect out of maven.

Comment: Hi @Andrew - Thank you for your reply. Yes I was already able to install maven and see those in my system. I tried to run 'mvn clean',  'mvn verify' and 'mvn test -e' and no errors.
Now, how can I run my test scripts? my java classes that I made.

How can I add those plugins?

My POM looks like is above: I've updated my issue. Please see.

Comment: And btw, as you can see in my code, I don't have any 'main'. Is that an issue? because there is an error looking for that.

Comment: Updating your POM is as simple as pasting the code inside. See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html for the format. 

Maven code execution does not require a main method, it actually looks for classes named with the word "Test" at the beginning or end of the file name. In your case, you would be using a TestNG style test suite. Check out https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/how-to-execute-testng-tests-with-maven-build/ for the specifics on how to write a TestNG suite that runs through Maven.

Comment: I have edited my original response to be a more complete answer to your questions in this comment chain, so please read above

Comment: can I know the code to execute java class without main? I can't execute this one because I don't have any main class, i only have a java class - mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"

Comment: Maven does not care about main, it only cares about having a test class. I embedded my TestNG Test class above to show you an example. Using the maven commands such as "mvn verify" or "mvn test" are how you run them.